# How to read a data frame in txt.file that doesn't have separator or fixed width with pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm working on a raw data which is a text file. However, it doesn't have separator or fixed width. Each column has different length. For example, the length of column 1 is 12; the length of column 2 is 5; and so forth.[image: The definition of the file is something like this]

I was wondering is there a function from some packages that can handle this kind of file given the length of each column. One way I think that may work is using regular expression to iterate each row and column.

Comment: This looks to be the schema of a database table. If your table is exported to a text file usually a delimiter is specified (tab/comma). You can even use multiple spaces `\s+` with pandas' `read_table()`. Please show us the text file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the txt file doesn't use tab/ space/ comma to separate the column. The only thing I know is the length of the columns. That's the reason why I want to see if there's any function available for this kind of file.

Comment: I think something simpler would be: `read_csv(..., delim_whitespace=True)`.

Comment: How was text file produced? Again, please show us a few rows. You're telling us what you think but not showing us what it is.

Comment: The file can be downloaded here: https://mega.nz/#!ElpTHJJQ!2qxUYMhxBXubtwIwjboeN3ihQMJqjCNDEJgo-FmAFiw

Comment: I don't know how was the file produced. It's an awful type of export data in my opinion. The problem with using read_csv is that the string in some columns has multiple spaces, such as street name and numbers in the address.

Answer (score 4):

This is still a fixed width file (that just means size of each field is fixed, it does not have to be equal). So you can use `pandas.read_fwf`, with the `widths` argument as `[21,5,5,12...]` to read this.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html

Comment: All be damned, I had no idea this existed.

Comment: This is the exact thing I'm looking for! All hail Pandas!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, **assuming there are no separators**, would just be to hard code the string slices:

```
with open("text.txt", "r+") as fh:
  for row in fh:
    row.write(row[0:12]+","+row[12:17]+","+row[17:23]... ) #finish
```

Then you could just specify the separator when you create the dataframe.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the method I tried! Thanks again.